# Obtener la llave de un JSON en PHP? (No el valor sino la llave)

Tags: php, json, postgresql

tengo un JSON Object que lo envio desde android a PHP
es similar a este

```
{"1":"insert 1", "2":"insert 2", "3":"insert 3" }
```

el numero es el id del registro y el inser es una instruccion sql que se ejecuta para guardar valores en una BASE ahora necesito devolver a mi aplicación android en ID de cada sentencia ejecutada. la sentencia se ejecuta bien pero no se como meter a una array esos ID que son la llave de cada JSON
aqui el codigo que uso en el servidor:

```
foreach ($capturas as $cap ) {  
    foreach ($cap as $key ) {
        $result = pg_query($dbconn,$key) or die("falla");
    }   
    $insertedArray[]=$cap;  
}
```

Es en el insertedArray donde necesito guardar los ID

Comment: la variable `$cap` es el json que muestras ya convertido a php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
foreach($capturas as $cap) {
    foreach($cap as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

En **$key** obtendrás los nombres de las llaves y en el **$val** obtendrás los valores

Comment: gracias me ha funcionado